# Кракозяблы при чтении файла мешают нормально сделать Split

Tags: c#

Есть фаил с текстом:

```
<координата x1> <координата y1>
<координата x2> <координата y2>
<координата x3> <координата y3>
<координата x4> <координата y4>
```

мне нужно отсплитить все ненужное и оставить только цифры, НО при загрузке файла и вывода его в консоль он выдает кучу вопросиков, не понимая русские буквы. Это проблема №1.
Проблема №2: как отсплитить отрезав целое слово не вбивая его по буквам?

ну и сам код, я новичок так что не ругайтесь а делайте заметки ко всем адекватными прислушаюсь

```
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        string[] coords = text.Split(' ', '\n', 'x', 'y', '<', '>', 'к', 'о', 'р', 'д', 'и', 'н', 'а', 'т');



        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[0]);
        int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[1]);
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[2]);
        int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[3]);
        int x3 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[4]);
        int y3 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[5]);
        int x4 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[6]);
        int y4 = Convert.ToInt32(coords[7]);

        Console.WriteLine("введите значение Х: ");
        int xP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("введите значение Y: ");
        int yP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.WriteLine(text + coords[1] +" ");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: А почему не `RegEx`? Выбрать числа, отпилив другое

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться перегруженным методом [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx)
с указанием исходной кодировки.

Comment: как? можно кодом написать? я не понимаю

Comment: В приведенной ссылке есть примеры использования, все довольно прозрачно. Хотя бы попытайтесь.

Answer (score -1):

1. Как уже подсказали попробуйте регулярные выражения.
   Примерно так:

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       var strings = new List<string>();
       strings.Add("<координата x1565> <координата y1234>");
       strings.Add("<координата x243> <координата y2442>");
       strings.Add("<координата x343> <координата y34433>");

       //Условие по которому искать. 
       //Нужные блоки выделяются скобками, чтобы потом найти их через группы
       var pattern = @"<координата x(\d+[.,]?\d+)> <координата y(\d+[.,]?\d+)>"; 

       foreach(var str in strings)
       {
           Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
           //Группа с индексом 0 - это само найденное выражение.
           //Координата Х - индекс группы 1
           //Координата У - индекс группы 2
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("x: {0}, y: {1}", match.Groups[1], match.Groups[2]));
       }   
   }
   ```
2. Вопросики на консоли.
   Скорей всего файл у Вас в win1251 кодировке, а консол в юникоде.
   Переконвертируйте файл в другую кодировку.